What approach should follow to solve Cache issue in spring boot
I have the following code for getting data from db.
    @Cacheable()
    public List<SystemDTO> getAllSystem(String client,Integer pageNumber,Integer pageSize,String sortBy, String sortDirection)
    {
        Pageable p=PageRequest.of(pageNumber,pageSize,sort);
        Page<SystemEntity> sys=sysDao.findAll(p);
        List<SystemEntity> allsys=sys.getContent();
        return allsys;
    }

And following code for adding new entity
    @CachePut()
    public SystemEntity addSystem(String client,SystemEntity sys) 
    {
        Integer maxId = sysDao.findSystemMaxId();
        System.out.println("maxId"+maxId);
        sys.setSystemId(maxId);
        sys.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        System.out.println(sys);
        return sysDao.save(sys);
    }

If I am not wrong, we should use the same key for @Cacheable and @Cacheput. But we dont have any common variable to use as key. Please help out of this. Thanks in advance.
Please give us the code using key of @Cacheable and @Cacheput.

You can't put two different object types (SystemDTO and SystemEntity) in a single cache

Okay thank you, imagine the return type is SystemDTO. What keys we need to provide for @Cachable and @Cacheput?

You could use two caches similar to the example here
public class Pageable {
   int pageNumber;
   int pageSize;
   String sortDirection;

   // TODO equals() and hashCode()
}

public class SystemService {
    // results from this method stored in the 'systems' cache
    @Cacheable(cacheName="systems", key="{ #client, #pageable }")
    public List<SystemDTO> getAllSystem(String client, Pageable pageable) { ... }
  
    // results from this method stored in the 'system' cache
    @CachePut(cacheName="system", key="{ #client, #sys.id }")
    @CacheEvict(cacheName="systems", allEntries = true)
    public SystemDTO addSystem(String client, SystemEntity sys) { ... }

    // results from this method sourced from the 'system' cache (or stored on cache miss)
    @Cacheable(cacheName="system", key="{ #client, #systemId }")
    public SystemDTO getSystem(String client, Long systemId) { ... }
}


Thanks for code mate. Now I got a new doubt, can't we write the code without using the evict? And will it work because we are using 2 different keys for getAll() and addSystem? could you please clarify me.

I added a getSystem(...) method to show how the system cache would be used.  Basically there's two seperate caches. The "systems" cache stores results from getAllSystem(...). Any time you add a system you'll need to flush the systems cache since the result of a call to getAllSystem(...) might change. I'm not sure how you could make this more granular (eg only evict the entries in the "systems" cache for the given client)
